# How to count how many times criteria in one column matches, with criteria in another column

Tags: excel

See example below.

A

1. electric_bike
2. docked_bike
3. classic_bike

B

1. member
2. casual

I'm trying to figure out how many times certain criteria in column B, matches up with certain criteria in column A.

To be more specific, how do I figure out how many times "casual" in column A matches with "docked_bike" in column B.

I want to figure out how many docked_bikes casual and members each ride.

Comment: To find out how many use COUNTIFS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.